# How to prevent a service from stopping on Error

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, windows-services

I wrote a Windows Service that polls data on some timeintervalls and writes them in database. 
But if there occures an Error writing to Database and the service stops. 
I want a robust solution that goes on even if an error occures.

I put try/catch bocks around every action that is done by the service in OnStart, OnStop and Dispose but it sopped anyway.

is try/catch the correct approach?
And where do I have to put it? 
Will it help to put try/catch in Main method?

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you try wrapping your database calls in a `TransactionScope` block? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your call in a TransactionScope, this will roll back any failed changes you are trying to make and should not break on failure.

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
   {
      DeleteStuff();
      UpdateStuff();
      scope.Complete();
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, i will inform myself about that and try it. :)

Comment: Very good, hope that helps you out.  I used this in a recent project where I was updating catalog information and if it failed it corrupted the database, so I decided that using a transaction was the better approach.

Comment: I could not try it yet, because I am still busy with other projects and the error did not occure again. But I will inform you when there is news.